# Can I turn off Ability Tips?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

When I use Overwatch, for instance, I have to go through an extra menu to use the ability where the game "explains" what the ability does. You'd think that by the 50th mission, I'd have figured out how to use these abilites but the game assumes I'm an idiot. How do I turn off the Ability Tips then?

Answer (score 16):

It really isn't about the tip, it's about showing confirmation button. I've spend considerable amount of time trying to figure out how to turn this off and found nothing.

However, whenever you're using keyboard shortcut, there is no confirmation needed.

Default bindings you can use:

- <kbd>Y</kbd> — overwatch
- <kbd>R</kbd> — reload
- <kbd>X</kbd> — toggle primary/secondary weapon
- <kbd>B</kbd> — hunker down
- <kbd>1</kbd> - <kbd>9</kbd>  — abilities, counting left from right (annoying to use, as this constantly changes)
- <kbd>F2</kbd> - <kbd>F11</kbd> — targets

Comment: As mentioned, get used to using the direct keys when possible, the numbers change from unit to unit and move to move. Personally, I bind overwatch to ` so it is easy to overwatch/tab through all remaining soldiers.

Answer (score 6):

If you are playing on the PC version, just use keyboard shortcut 'Y' for Overwatch. IMO, pop-ups serve as confirmation on your decision so you can back out. Keyboard shortcuts are riskier especially if you are playing Ironman mode.

Comment: Yeah, I can't tell you how many times having the popup has saved my ass in ironman mode when I accidentally click the wrong icon. Now if only they'd add confirmation for moving (through an option maybe), accidentally moving to an open spot because you tried to click on a higher elevation and the game assumed you wanted to move behind it is not fun.

Comment: What's that, you want to jump off of the ladder out of cover to see if you really can make friends with Mr. Chryssalid? Crap.

Comment: Yeah, it seems as though the game randomly decides whether to use left-click as "select the nearest unit" or "move unit to this location" or "open the nearest door" (even if that door is **nowhere** near your cursor).

Answer (score 2):

On PC, you can double-click the Overwatch button, which works as well.